# How can I simplify a conjunction of disjunctions (CNF) statement if I can introduce extra variables?

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

I have a CNF statement.such as
$(x_{1} \lor x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor x_3 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor x_3 \lor x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor x_3 \lor \lnot x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4)$

If I can introduce extra variables, how can I simplify it?

Comment: How about simplifying things like _(x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor x_4) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor \lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4)_ first?